# Failed to parse the XML iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using the below code to parse the downloaded file, previously before restarting my mac it was working fine but now it says Failed to parse the XML, while the data need to be downloaded is being shown properly.

```
-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender{

    NSString *user = [userNameField text];

    NSString *passwd = [passwordField text];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:user forKey:@"Username"];

    [defaults setObject:passwd forKey:@"Password"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Data Saved");

    NSString *urlAsString = @"http";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *error) {

         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){

             NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSLog(@"HTML = %@", html);

         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded."); 

         }

         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);
        } }];


    NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"xml"];

    NSData *xml = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];

    self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];

    self.xmlParser.delegate = self;

    if ([self.xmlParser parse]) {

        NSLog(@"The XML is parsed");

    }else{

        NSLog(@"Failed to parse the XML");
    }
}

-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    self.rootElement = nil;
    self.currentElementPointer = nil; }

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if (self.rootElement == nil){
        self.rootElement = [[XMLElement alloc] init]; self.currentElementPointer = self.rootElement;
    } else {
        XMLElement *newElement = [[XMLElement alloc] init]; newElement.parent = self.currentElementPointer; [self.currentElementPointer.subElements addObject:newElement]; self.currentElementPointer = newElement;
    }
    self.currentElementPointer.name = elementName; self.currentElementPointer.attributes = attributeDict;

    NSString *user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"user"]];

    NSLog(@"User: %@", user);

    if ([user isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"Test succeeded!");
    }    
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if ([self.currentElementPointer.text length] > 0){
        self.currentElementPointer.text =
        [self.currentElementPointer.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    } else {
        self.currentElementPointer.text = string; }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    self.currentElementPointer = self.currentElementPointer.parent; 

}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{ 

    self.currentElementPointer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On failure to parse the XML you should look at `-(NSError *)parseError` to see where exactly the error lies.

```
NSLog(@"Parse Error: %@", [self.xmlParser parseError]);
```

This isn't a direct answer to your question but as you have not actually asked one (*?*) I wouldn't know where to start other than there.